# SUMIF twice for the same field in an SQL query in MS Access

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a table containing a list of "Money in Money Out" amounts along with dates and client IDs.

The `MIMO` field contains a positive number if the record is money in and a negative number if money out.

I want to perform a query that sums `MIMO` but to give the total money in and money out separately for all records between 2 dates. It does this by summing only if the amount is >0 for money in, and the vice-versa for money out.

I have this at the moment but I beleive my syntax is completely wrong:

```
SELECT Sum(MIMO.MIMO) AS SumOfMIMO HAVING (((Sum(MIMO.MIMO))>0), Sum(MIMO.MIMO) AS SumOfMIMO1 HAVING ((Sum(MIMO.MIMO))<0), MIMO.AccountNum
FROM MIMO
GROUP BY MIMO.TransactionDate, MIMO.AccountNum
WHERE ((MIMO.TransactionDate) Between #12/1/2012# And #12/31/2012#) AND ((MIMO.AccountNum)="12345"));
```

Comment: No point grouping by AccountNum if you also filter by it !

Comment: I'm sure, the statement was semi-generated by Access and I've tried to manipulate it to do the above, so there will definitely be syntax errors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `IIF`:

```
SELECT  SUM(IIF(MIMO.MIMO >= 0,MIMO.MIMO,0)) AS MoneyIn,
        SUM(IIF(MIMO.MIMO < 0,MIMO.MIMO,0)) AS MoneyOut
FROM MIMO
WHERE ((MIMO.TransactionDate) Between #12/1/2012# And #12/31/2012#)) 
AND ((MIMO.AccountNum)="12345"));
```

Comment: That's the trick! I wasn't aware of IIF. You missed an open bracket after the `AND` but otherwise works great. Thanks

Comment: @harryg Thanks, I edited the open bracket issue. But it was like that on the query you posted ;-)

Comment: Yes my attempt was a bit of a mess, SQL's not my strong point!

Answer (score 1):

You could also calculate this with a Pivot:

```
TRANSFORM Sum(Mimo.Mimo) AS Expr1
SELECT AccountNum, TransactionDate
FROM Mimo
WHERE Sgn([Mimo])<>0 And TransactionDate Between #12/1/2012# And #12/31/2012#
GROUP BY AccountNum, TransactionDate
PIVOT Sgn([Mimo]);
```